# Workaround 3rd party and advertisers in Safari extension

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, safari-extension

I am working on a Safari extension that communicates with a web service. When the Block cookies option in the Safari Preferences is set to "Block cookies from 3rd parties and advertisers"  is selected, I am unable to log into the web service from the extension.

I am using jQuery to make all my Ajax requests. Is there a work around to make this work?

If I set the option block cookies to "never", the authentication works.